# Minimum cost cut with discount - what is the complexity?

Tags: graph-theory, graph-algorithms

Consider an undirected graph $G=(V,E)$ with non-negative edge costs. Given an integer $k$ with $0\leq k\leq |E|$, let us call an edge set $C\subseteq E$ a *$k$-discounted cut*, if the following hold:

1. $C$ is a cut in the usual sense.
2. The cost of the $k$ most expensive edges in $C$ is changed to 0. (If $k\geq |C|$, then all edge costs in $C$ are changed to 0.) This cost reduction is the "discount." The cost of the $k$-discounted cut is the sum of the edge costs in $C$, after the cost reduction, i.e., the remaining cost after taking the discount.

**Task:** Given $k$, and the graph with edge costs,  find a  minimum cost $k$-discounted cut.

**Question:** Is anything known about this problem? Can it be solved in polynomial time?

*Note:* It is well known that the (conventional) minimum cost cut can be found in polynomial time. It is not clear, however, how the discount influences the complexity.

Comment: The variation (a form of network interdiction) where the source $s$ has to be disconnected from the sink $t$ is strongly NP-complete (see
[Deterministic Network Interdiction](https://faculty.nps.edu/kwood/docs/WoodDetNetInt93.pdf) by Kevin Wood; the proof applies to both directed and undirected graphs).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the connectivity interdiction problem, which can be solved in polynomial time [1].

> **(Unweighted) Connectivity interdiction**
>
> Given a graph $G$ and integer $k$. Find a set $R$ of $k$ edges, such that the min-cut in $G-R$ is minimized.

Your problem is the same as this problem because $R$ is the $k$ discounted edges in the minimum $k$-discounted cut.

Zenklusen's paper discusses a more general weighted version of the problem. Each edge has a weight (independent from cost). $R$ is chosen so the weight is at most $k$. That problem admits a PTAS. The special case we care about is when the weights are all $1$, which is the case solvable in polynomial time.

1. *Zenklusen, Rico*, [**Connectivity interdiction**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.orl.2014.07.010),  [ZBL06945298](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:06945298)..

Comment: For those who cannot access the article, can you add why the abstract talks of PTAS (and confirm whether as stated the problem is the "special case [that can] be solved efficiently").

Comment: I've updated my answer to include this discussion.

Comment: It is quite interesting that the $s-t$ connectivity interdiction is NP-complete (see comment to the original question), while the global connectivity interdiction is in P, but only for the unweighted case. The weighted case becomes NP-complete again, but it has a PTAS, according to the referenced article.

Comment: It is very common for this kind of problem. The weighted case gives us a knapsack constraint.